# Delphi FireMonkey iOS App: Error while Deploying to iPhone Simulator 8.1

Tags: ios, iphone, delphi, xcode6, firemonkey

I am working on a simple iOS App using Delphi FireMonkey.

I am using Delphi XE7 in Virtual Windows 7 OS and a Mac OS with XCode 6.1

I have done the following steps:

-> Activated the iOS Simulator as my target platform in the Project Manager.

-> Created and activated a Connection profile for the OS X platform and the Test Connection is success.

-> Added an SDK for iPhone Simulator 8.1 on the SDK Manager.

-> paserver version 6.0.2.17 is running both in Mac OS and Windows OS. XCode is running on my Mac and iPhone simulator 8.1 is also started but no response.

> **Error**: Session start error: Simulator session timed out..

Above error remains same, even if I change the previous version of the iPhone Simulator.

Can anyone help me out regarding this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XE7 cannot deploy to iOS Simulator 8.1 yet. I think EMB needs some time to build an update for XE7 to address the new XCode and SDKs, but with an hotfix you can deploy to iOS7 Simulator which can be installed in XCODE via Preferences.

[Hotfix for PAServer](http://community.embarcadero.com/index.php/blogs/entry/paserver-hotfix-for-delphi-xe7-and-rad-studio-xe7-to-support-ios-7-1-simulator-in-xcode-6)

Comment: Thanks, Hotfix for PAServer works but anyhow still we need to wait for 8.0 version.